# Behaviors из других методов в Yii2

Tags: php, классы, yii2, behaviors

Мне известно, что поведения можно настраивать переопределяя метод behaviors, который будет возвращать массив с конфигурациями каждого прикреплённого поведения.
Я хочу, чтобы помимо этого метода, был ещё другой, предположим,  behaviors2, формат которого был индентичен, который делал бы абсолютно то же самое — хранил данные о поведениях.

Задача такова: собирать информацию о поведениях из обоих методов.

Исследовав код компонентов, я понял, что за сбор информации из метода behaviors отвечает ensureBehaviors, который в свою очередь запускается чуть ли не в начале каждого другого метода, который хоть как-то связан с поведениями.
Первая мысль — переопределить его:

```
public function ensureBehaviors()
{
    parent::ensureBehaviors();

    $this->ensureBehaviors2();//для красоты можно использовать static::
}
```

Где я в ensureBehaviors2 как раз и прикреплю все остальные поведения.

Трудность: метод, который отвечает за прикрепление поведения к компоненту, attachBehaviorInternal является приватным, а метод attachBehavior вызывает ensureBehaviors. Итого: рекурсия.

Выход: добавить в класс свойство:

```
private $_ensureBehaviorsLock = false;
```

И написать вот так:

```
public function ensureBehaviors()
{
    if ($this->_ensureBehaviorsLock) {
        return;
    }
    $this->_ensureBehaviorsLock = true;

    parent::ensureBehaviors();

    $this->ensureBehaviors2();
}
```

И тут я задумался.. Вроде бы работает, но похоже на большой и тяжёлый костыль. Но работает. Хочется узнать ваше мнение и возможные решения этой задачки.

Вот мой набросок, чтобы было ясно, чего я хочу: http://pastebin.com/1pVaVvmq

Несколько оговорок:

Функционал метода behaviors должен остаться прежним. Знаю, что можно было бы использовать behaviors2 и behaviors3, а в behaviors просто мержить результаты этих методов. Или в behaviors дописать функционал, который брал массив, который в нём, и мержил с другими. Но тогда нельзя было бы использовать наследование.

P.s. у кого есть привилегия редактировать вопросы, отформатируйте, пожалуйста, по-человечески. Пишу с телефона, возможности такой нет.

Comment: Мдааа... Xenial Xerus. `Задача такова: собирать информацию о поведениях из обоих методов.` Можно поподробнее, зачем такие извращения? Вам нужно сохранить состоние поведений до выполнения определённого экшена и после?

Comment: Разделить зону ответственности и добавить дополнительный функционал, не затронув прежний. Может путь решения моей изначальной задачи не очень, но значительно упрощает мне жизнь.

Comment: Ок. Допустим у вас два набора поведений. Далее, вы как собираетесь определить какой набор дёргать, а какой нет? Как это будет осуществляться через роутинг? Обычно для расширения функционала не затрагивая legacy-код, используют [паттерн "декоратор"](http://dron.by/post/pattern-proektirovaniya-dekorator-decorator-na-php.html)

Comment: А я разве не описал, как это должно работать? Мне нужно не переписать класс, а создать новый, наследовавшись от него и дополнив функционал.

Comment: Все названия методов и свойств весьма условны и написаны исключительно для примера. В реальном проекте все немного по-другому.

Comment: Кстати, `Или в behaviors дописать функционал, который брал массив, который в нём, и мержил с другими. Но тогда нельзя было бы использовать наследование.` Почему нельзя, [вот же](http://pastebin.com/A4AUXfrd).

Comment: Я хочу создать класс с поддержкой двух методов, в которых хранятся данные о поведениях, которые будут предназначены для разных целей. Как будет реализовываться сбор данных, это будет забота именно этого класса, от которого я буду наследоваться. Я не хочу запихивать функционал в методы behaviors, а хочу, чтобы было два метода, которые будут просто возвращать массивы. Я не прошу альтернативной задачи, а прошу разобраться с правильной реализацией текущей.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы один и тот же запрос конкретной модели выполнялся в разных ситуация с разным набором поведений, т.е. передавать в модель ваше свойство `ensureBehaviorsLock`? Почему не создать [разные модели](http://pastebin.com/5qJb1CLZ) со своим набором поведений. Либо создать метод-контейнер и динамически подмешивать поведения в зависимости от условий. Данную логику можно реализовать через [`attachBehaviors()`](https://goo.gl/3oW8t3) примерно [так](http://pastebin.com/VsBr5Pg6). Можно даже из контроллера передавать поведения, но это неверно - поведения модели должны хранится в самой модели.

Answer (score 1):

Я посоветую вам отказаться от идеи разделить подключаемые поведения на несколько методов. Вот мои аргументы:

- Нестандартный механизм. Да, мы должны программировать с использованием фреймворка, а не на фреймворке. Но первый аргумент такой что все знают что такое `behaviors`. Что такое `analyticsBehaviors`, `customBehaviors` придется всем объяснять.
- Ложная гибкость. Вам недостаточно в одном месте добавить `behaviors2`. Я предполагаю что вы выберите другое название и вопрос в том всем ли моделям это будет нужно. А что если некоторым понадобится `behaviors3`? Код который вы привели не является костылем, может только немного. Он адекватно решает задачу разделения, но я не думаю что это будет достаточно гибко.

Стандартное решение этой задачи для меня выглядит вполне нормальным и максимально гибким.

```
class Model extends \yii\base\Model
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return ArrayHelper::merge([
            'AnalyticBehavior' => [
                'class' => AnalyticBehavior::className()
            ]
        ], $this->getCustomBehaviors());
    }

    private function getCustomBehaviors()
    {
        return [
            'NotifyBehavior' => [
                'class' => NotifyBehavior::className()
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Не нужно гадать что где и как. Стандартный behaviors, их большое количество можно раскидать как захочется.

Проблема с наследованием решается так:

```
class ChildModel extends Model
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return ArrayHelper::merge([
            'StrictAnalyticBehavior' => [
                'class' => StrictAnalyticBehavior::className()
            ]
        ], parent::behaviors());
    }
}
```

Программист всегда будет работать с `behaviors`, способы формирования которого будут определяться задачей. Это просто и круто.